# Error al usar array_diff

Tags: php

Tengo este codigo, el cual coge los valores de array y los separa en piezas, 16 piezas de 4 valores cada uno que se guardan en $matriz, hasta ahi todo genial, la funcion bordes lo que hace es encontrar que piezas tienen dos ceros y almacenarlas en otra variable para poder usarlas individualmente mas adelante en la variable $borde, esto funciona y si hago un print_r de $borde todo funciona perfecto, pero a la hora de eliminar esos valores de $matriz no puedo hacerlo, ni con array_diff($piezas, $borde), ni con unset($piezas[$i]), ya que con array_diff() me salta el error: 'Array to string conversion' en la linea:  `$piezasSinBordes = array_diff($piezas, $borde);` y con unset(), el error: Undefined offset: 4 y Trying to access array offset on value of type null las dos se corresponden a la linea: `if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0)`, ayuda, muchas gracias a todos de antemano

```
<?php

$array = [4, 4,
    2, 5, 4, 0,
    2, 1, 4, 2,
    0, 1, 1, 0,
    4, 4, 0, 3,
    0, 0, 4, 3,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 4, 0, 0,
    4, 4, 3, 5,
    5, 5, 2, 4,
    1, 1, 0, 5,
    4, 1, 0, 4,
    1, 0, 2, 4,
    3, 5, 1, 2,
    1, 4, 2, 0,
    0, 1, 5, 2,
    1, 5, 0, 4];


$matriz = array(array());
$borde = array(array());


function piezas($arrayPiezas){

    $length = count($arrayPiezas);
    $alto = $arrayPiezas[0];
    $ancho = $arrayPiezas[1];
    global $matriz;
    
    $arrPiezas = array_slice($arrayPiezas, 2);

    for($i = 1; $i < ($length/$alto); $i++){
        
        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){

            $matriz[$i-1][$j] = $arrPiezas[0];
            array_shift($arrPiezas);

        }
    }
}

function bordes($piezas){
   
    global $borde;
    global $array;

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($piezas); $i++) {

        $contador = 0;
    
        for($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++){
           
            if($piezas[$i][$j] == 0){

                $contador++;
                
                if($contador == 2){

                    $borde[$i] = $piezas[$i];
                    //unset($piezas[$i]);
                    //print_r($piezas);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    $piezasSinBordes = array_diff($piezas, $borde);
    print_r($piezas);
    print_r($piezasSinBordes);
}

piezas($array);

bordes($matriz);


?>
```